# mysql show all the inserted data of today

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table called as invoice in Mysql like this

```
id(id)
store_name(varchar)
description(text)
created_at(DATETIME)
```

Now I have multiple invoices with different created date in my database table. Now I want to show all the invoices which has been created today. So can someone kindly tell me how to do this

```
$recentinvoice = mysql_query(
    "select * from tbl_invoices WHERE create_at = CURDATE()"
);

while($invoices=mysql_fetch_array($recentinvoice)) {
    echo $invoices['store_name'];
    echo $invoices['description'];
    echo $invoices['name'];
    echo $invoices['created_at'];
}
```

but it is not showing anything. So any help and suggestions from all of you will be reallly appreciable. Thanks

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: if i am not mistaken its `DATE_FORMAT(created_date, "%Y-%m-%d") = CURDATE()`

Comment: Your query is quite ok, but you need small changes .Try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your `WHERE`:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_invoices WHERE create_at >= CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go, please let me know if it works or doesn't.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_invoices 
WHERE DATE(created_at) = DATE(NOW());
```

- DATE() returns the date without time
- NOW() returns the current date & time (note we’ve used the DATE() function in this query to remove the time)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tbl_invoices WHERE create_at = now()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :-

> select * from tbl_invoices WHERE
>   date_format(create_at,'%Y-%m-%d')=CURDATE();

Also its recommended to find the format of date inside the database and according that you have to compare.Read more about [date_format()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Try to make your both side date format same.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Its better assign current date into the variable and then pass it to the sql where condition.

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$recentinvoice=mysql_query("select * from tbl_invoices WHERE create_at = '$today' ");
```

just try. Thanks